# Python on Php import troubles

Tags: php, python, python-import, shell-exec, opencv

I'm calling a py script from php and everything seems ok untill I import cv2, then the troubles start.

Situation:

1# I have a folder test/ with test.php and test_script.py.

test.php:

```
<?php

$command = escapeshellcmd( 'python test_script.py' );
$output = shell_exec($command);

echo $output;
```

test_script.py:

```
import os
import json
import numpy as np
import cv2
print('pol')
```

2# If I run it I visualize nothing in test/test.php; instead if I comment "import cv2" it runs perfectly visualizing "pol" as output.

3# The path variable called by php is the same called by cmd (yes, windows..)

4# in cmd I can easily call:

```
> python test_script.py
```

and it works fine

Specs
Php:7.2.2
Python: 3.6.5 on Anaconda3

So, how can I make it work the same on php?? Why is not working even if in cmd it works?

Thank you in advance

*Update #1*
my sdout returns:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "predict_test.py", line 10, in 
      import cv2
  ImportError: DLL load failed: Access is denied.

but I already set Full control permissions by Users and System, on Anaconda3 folder.

Comment: Is cv2 installed in the environment you are using? You are probably getting an error, so make sure you are checking stderr as well as stdout.

Comment: Yes. I installed cv2 in base environment, the same I think php naturally invokes for python. My stdout (niice tip, thank you) gives me:<br>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_script.py", line 10, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: Access is denied.


_ So it looks like a permission problem, but I already set full control to Users and System on the Anaconda3 folder and subfolders